# it is not navigating user to page they should be on

Tags: php

below I have scenario of what SHOULD happen:

- User is on `create_session.php` page, so the other pages in the array are
  locked out
- If user tries to access another page they are displayed with the div
  box shown above:
- If user selects Continue link then it should navigate the user to the
  page they should be on which was `create.php` page

The problem is that if the user accesses another page and the div box appears, if user click on the `Continue` link, it does not navigate back to the `create_session.php` page or in other words the page the user was last on.

The url does not seem to change after clicking on the `Continue` Link

Why is it not navigating the user to the page they should be on after clicking on `Continue`?

The script that tries to control which pages are locked out and keeping the page the user is on unlocked is in this script `steps.php` which is shown below:

```
<?php

function allowed_in(){

$steps = array('create_session.php', 'QandATable.php', 'individualmarks.php', 'penalty.php', 'penaltymarks', 'complete.php');

// Track $latestStep in either a session variable
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = "";
}
$currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx > 1 ) {

   return true;

} else {

    return false;

}

}

?>
```

Now each script stored in the arrays contains the code `include('steps.php')` and contains the code below:

```
        <?php

if (allowed_in()){

//create_session.php code

}else{
?>

<div class="boxed">
<a href="<?php echo $steps[$latestIdx + 1] ?>">Continue</a>
</div>

<?php   

}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

When I click on `Continue` link, in url it displayed two errors which were below:

> notice: Undefined variable: latestIdx in ... on line 1636
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: steps in ... on line 1636

Notices are displayed for this line below:

`<a href="<?php echo $steps[$latestIdx + 1] ?>">Continue</a>`

**UPDATE 2:**

When I navigate to a page which is locked (in other words when the box which states you have to `Continue` appears, I am getting undefined `$_SESSION` variables and I am also getting this error: `Undefined variable: steps in steps.php on line 57`

For the `$_SESSION` undefined errors, is it because I am placing the $_SESSION variables in the wrong place? And how can I stop the undefined variable of steps in steps.php?

Below is an example `QandATable.php` order of code looks like:

```
    <?php

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
    require_once 'init.php'; 
    //12 hours sessions

    session_start();
    include('steps.php'); //exteranlised steps.php

    <head>

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

    }


    if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
                //Declare my counter for the first time

                $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
                $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
                $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;

        }

    elseif (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
        $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    }

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php 

//once session is expired, it should log the user out, but at mo this isn't happening
    if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){ //checks if user is logged in

        if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed"){

    //QandATable.php code:

    }else{

    $page = allowed_in()+1;


    ?>

    <div class="boxed">
      <a href="<?php echo $steps[$page] ?>">Continue with Current Assessment</a>

    <?php   

    }

    }else{ 

    echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>"; 
    //show above echo if user is not logged in

    }

    ?>
```

Below is the full steps.php:

```
<?php

$steps = array(1 =>'create_session.php',2 => 'QandATable.php',3 => 'individualmarks.php',4 => 'penalty.php',5 => 'penaltymarks',6 => 'complete.php');

function allowed_in($steps){
// Track $latestStep in either a session variable
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = 0;
}
$currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx == 1 )
    {
       $currentIdx = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
       return 'Allowed';
    }
    return $latestIdx;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed the value of `$_SESSION`? Are you sure that it is in existence? Have you tried calling `session_start()` before you try accessing or setting values of the `$_SESSION`? In addition, based on the logic that you provided, I'm wondering if you need to have `$currentIdx - $latestIdx >= 1` - notice the `=` in there that I added. Just a couple of troubleshooting tips.

Comment: where does this come from ? `$pages[$currentPages+1]`

Comment: @JMax let me get working on the troubleshooting and i will keep you updated

Comment: @ROYFinley  Ah, I forgot that I changed the variable name, let me change it back and see what happens and I will let you know.

Comment: @Jmax steps.php does not contain session_start because it notifies me that I already have session_start() in create_session.php

Comment: @JMaxif I do the var_dump() you stated in steps.php, I get this: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in ... NULL `. if I do var_dump() in create_session.php which contains the session_start(), it does not have a `$_SESSION` variable known as `$_SESSION['latestStep']` What do I need to do to solve this. I can't put session_start also in the `steps.php` as that it says I already have a session started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx > 1 ) {

   return 1;

} else {

    return 0;

}
```

I think Should be this:

```
if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx >= 1 )
 {
    return true;
 } 
return false;
```

and not sure were this is coming from:

```
$pages[$currentPages+1]
```

Your steps array will need to be declared outside of the function as well
You have to return $latestIdx if yo plan to use it in the url. I am not sure if you are trying to go back or forward?

**Still not sure if i understand exactly what you want but this should be a start:**

```
 $steps = array(1 =>'create_session.php',2 => 'QandATable.php',3 => 'individualmarks.php',4 => 'penalty.php',5 => 'penaltymarks',6 => 'complete.php');
function allowed_in($steps)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep']))
        {
            $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
        }
        else
            {
                $latestStep = 0;
            }
            $currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx == 1 )
    {
       $currentIdx = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
       return 'Allowed';
    }
    return $latestIdx;
}
```

**and Page**

```
    if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed")
    {
        //create_session.php code
    }
    else
        {
$page = allowed_in()+1;
?>

<div class="boxed">
<a href="<?php echo $steps[$page] ?>">Continue</a>
</div>

<?php   

}

?>
```

Comment: it should be `$steps[$latestIdx + 1]`. when I click `Continue` link tho I get 2 errors which I will post underneath question. Check edit which includes the errors in 5 mins

Comment: What I am trying to do is that the user has to go through the pages in the same order as shown in the `array()`. Now lets say the user is on `QandATable.php`, but they have not finished filling out that page or they abandonded the page by trying to go on another page, the other pages will be locked out displaying a message that user has to continue. When the user clicks on `Continue` it will navigate the user back to `QandATable.php`, so the link could go back or forwards as the user could of tried to go back to one ofthe previous pages or tried to skip ahead to the other pages

Comment: working on it now for you, getting it to go both ways is tricky

Comment: Can I ask is your code only going to work for the example I mentiod in my question or will it work for all the pages? Easy way to say what I am trying to do is that all pages in array are locked except for the one the user is currently on. When the user finishes a page, then that page like the other will be locked and the next page will be unlocked (or in other words allowed)

Comment: When you have time can you please look at my UPDATE 2 section at bottom of question, having some more trouble with undefined indexes. It will show current layout of codef or steps.php and one of pages from the array